# What are the driving factors for performing a steep approach

Tags: aircraft-systems

What are the factors a pilot needs to consider before preparing for the steep approach?

How is steep approach combined with auto land feature.

[image]

Comment: This is a very broad question. Most aircraft require no certification for performing a steep approach. Airport requirements and pilot considerations vary widely with the situation. What industry sector are you considering in your question?

Comment: Okay I am mostly concerned from the aircraft perspective. When does pilot go for steep approach. What 'other' things need to be considered before engaging steep.

Comment: Usually a steep approach means they are avoiding an obstacle or have been asked by ATC to "make it short". A steep approach ends in a normal landing, if you are hitting the ground any harder than you do normally then you are performing the technique wrong. Speed can be managed in the approach so you are steep, but not fast, and it ends in a flare/touchdown just like any other landing. There are no certification requirements, but some aircraft are prohibited from slips or slips in certain configurations (like with full flaps).

Comment: Related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21956/what-is-the-requirement-of-a-higher-glidepath-approach-angle-and-is-this-a-fligh

Comment: @JonathanWalters in the US perhaps - in the EU, there are specific requirements for aircraft to perform a steep approach requiring certification from the EASA

Comment: Edited the question to include Jeppesen chart of London UK

Comment: On ILS if you're coming in steeper than the glide slope you have to be careful not pick up a  [false glide slope](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/160/8730)

Comment: Somewhat related [tactical penetration descent](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23529/8730)

Comment: How is auto-land combined with steep approach?

Comment: The three questions are rather loosely related, which is bad format for this site. Voting to close as too broad.